# Merge CSV file using Perl

Tags: windows, perl, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to merge using the following Perl code, but I am not able to run it. It is supposed to out put multiple text files, but it is not working.

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
#
$template_file_name="rtr-template.txt";
while(<>) {

   ($location, $name, $lo0ip, $frameip, $framedlci, $eth0ip, $x) 
       = split (/,/);

   open(TFILE, "< $template_file_name") || die "config template file $template_file_name: 
$!\n";
   $ofile_name = $name . ".txt";
   open(OFILE, "> $ofile_name") || die "output config file $ofile_name: $!\n";

   while (<TFILE>) {

     s/##location##/$location/;
     s/##rtrname##/$name/;
     s/##eth0-ip##/$eth0ip/;
     s/##loop0-ip##/$lo0ip/;
     s/##frame-ip##/$frameip/;
     s/##frame-DLCI##/$framedlci/;

     printf OFILE $_;
   }
}
```

The CSV file looks like this

```
Toronto, Router1, 172.25.15.1, 172.25.16.6,101, 172.25.100.1
```

And this the **rtr-template.txt** file

```
!
version 12.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname ##rtrname##
!
enable password cisco
enable secret cisco
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address ##loop0-ip## 255.255.255.255
!
interface Serial0/0
 description Frame-Relay Circuit 
 no ip address
 encapsulation frame-relay
 ip route-cache policy
 frame-relay lmi-type ansi
 no shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0.1 point-to-point
 ip address ##frame-ip## 255.255.255.252
 frame-relay interface-dlci ##frame-DLCI##
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description User LAN Segment
 ip address ##eth0-ip## 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
router eigrp 99
 network 172.25.0.0
!
snmp-server location ##location##
!
line con 0
 password cisco
 login
 transport input none
line aux 0
 password cisco
 login
line vty 0 4
 password cisco
 login
 transport input telnet
!
end
```

Comment: How do you run your program in the command line?

Comment: What i am doing is that opening the perl  going to the directory file perl, and then writing .

create-config.pl<RTR-Data.CSV
where RTR-DATA is the CSV file.

When i add this an empty .txt file is generated.

Comment: Could you add `printf "%s\n", join("/", ($location, $name, $lo0ip, $frameip, $framedlci, $eth0ip, $x) );` after `split()` to confirm that your `split()` working as expected and tell us the screen result.

Comment: Hello
i added what youve mentioned ad the screen displays, 2 new lines on the CMD,
1st :create-configs.pl<RTR-DATA.CSV
2nd://////
after enterning the create-configs.pl<RTR-DATA.CSV command

Comment: Then you know the `split()` is not working as expected. Are you sure RTR-DATA.CSV is a csv file? Can you show the content or maybe just first line of RTR-DATA.CSV ?

Comment: yeah sure, take a look,
Toronto, Router1, 172.25.15.1, 172.25.16.6,101, 172.25.100.1

Comment: DO you have any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: I test your program and it is creating Router1.txt properly.

Comment: Hello Tvin,

could you please tell me what command you are inserting ?

Comment: Because your RTR-DATA.CSV contains space, you better use `split(/, */)` instead. But I think this is not the reason of your issue.

Comment: This is how I run it: `echo "Toronto, Router1, 172.25.15.1, 172.25.16.6,101, 172.25.100.1" | ./create-configs.pl` , but the way you run it should be OK as well.

Comment: Hello,

iam  a beginner in perl, and iam using this code to generate a lare num of router config as ,txt file, 

WHAT I DID I INSTALLED  perl on my pc and then click on the create-configs.pl file a cmd is displayed i wrote <RTR-DATA.CSV,  and i noticed that an empty txt file is generated.

so what do you think the problem is from the code or from the CSV file?

Comment: I have run your command but an empty txt file is also generated named Router1.

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cisco-ios-cookbook/0596527225/ch01s16.html

this is the Cisco article from where i got the code.

Comment: Are you working on a Windows machine?

Comment: Usually you don't just click on a perl script which receive input from standard input. Open a terminal, go to the directory where the perl file and CSV file exist. Run from there.

Comment: Hello tvin pretty awsome, it worked finally :)

Maybe i wasnt opening the cmd i as run with administrator.

thank you :D

Comment: @user2600543: It is nothing to do with administrator status. Clicking on a file in Windows Explorer doesn't pass it any parameters, so `<>` is reading from your keyboard. I've explained in my solution below

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're running your program by double-clicking on its file name in Windows Explorer.

The way `<>` works is that it will read from any files that you specify on the command line (that appear in the `@ARGV` array) or, if that array is empty, then it will read from `STDIN` — usually the keyboard.

Double-clicking the file gives it no command-line parameters, so it waits for you to type input in the black window that appears. That means you've entered `<RTR-DATA.CSV` as input to your `while` loop and Perl has tried to split it on commas, giving only a single field, so it sets `$location` to `<RTR-DATA.CSV`. Not what you wanted!

So, if you run your program from the `cmd` window by entering

```
create-configs.pl RTR-DATA.CSV
```

then within the program `@ARGV` will contain `RTR-DATA.CSV` and the `<>` will automatically read from that file

Here are some further notes on your code

- There is no need for the `#!` line on a Windows system, which will normally have the `.pl` file extension tied to the perl executable
- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write, and declare all your variables at their first point of use. That would have given some very strong clues about the nature of your problem
- You should normally `chomp` each line read from a file, as it will have a newline character at the end that can cause problems if you leave it at the end of the last field returned by `split`
- In this case you should also probably add optional whitespace either side of the comma in the pattern you are splitting on, so as to remove leading and trailing spaces from the fields it returns
- You should always use lexical file handles (`$out_fh` instead of `OFILE`) with the three-parameter form of `open`

And here's a rewrite of your code that takes into account all of those points. I hope it helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $template_file = 'rtr-template.txt';

while ( <> ) {

    chomp;
    my ($location, $name, $lo0ip, $frameip, $framedlci, $eth0ip) = split /\s*,\s*/;

    open my $t_fh, '<', $template_file
        or die qq{Unable to open "$template_file" for input: $!};

    my $out_file = "$name.txt";
    open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file
        or die qq{Unable to open "$out_file" for output: $!};

    while (<$t_fh>) {

        s/##location##/$location/g;
        s/##rtrname##/$name/g;
        s/##eth0-ip##/$eth0ip/g;
        s/##loop0-ip##/$lo0ip/g;
        s/##frame-ip##/$frameip/g;
        s/##frame-DLCI##/$framedlci/g;

        printf $out_fh $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Text::CSV to parse the CSV file and Template Toolkit or similar to do the templating. Don't reinvent the wheel.